# How do you use protractor.js in the context of Angulars documentation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I'm reading the documentation for Angular, and there is usually a file called `protractor.js` included with each code sample.

For example, [this page of documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module) - among many.

A Google search revealed that `protractor` is a way of testing Angular code. But I can't find any guides about how to use this file - especially in the context of the Angular tutorial.

Is there any way to see the `protractor.js` file within the online plunkr environment, or anything like that?

Answer (score 1):

Protractor is a tool built on top of WebdriverJS with customisations to make the testing of Angular easier.

FYR, please visit the link on github to get a basic understanding(http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/)

This is another useful link for understanding Protractor(http://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/testing-angularjs-apps-protractor)

Hope that helped!